# Why is my Canon Powershot A1100 focusing only on the bottom part of scenes?

Tags: canon, autofocus, focus, point-and-shoot, troubleshooting

I've been using a Canon PowerShot A1100 IS camera for the past year and it had been working just fine until I decided to change its settings. After I had serious trouble with it, I reset the settings and thought everything would go back to normal but it didn't. As you can see on the picture, the camera focuses only on the bottom part but not on the upper part. This happens not only with landscape pictures but also with any other type. Do you think this is a setting issue or a mechanical problem?

Sample image: 
[image: sample]

Comment: It looks like one of the elements in the lens is physically misaligned to me. The road in in focus to a distance well past the church steeple, so the steeple *should* be in focus, but it is not. This may very well be a hardware problem.

Comment: You've got yourself a built in tilt-shift lens, these can cost a ton :D

Comment: @FakeName I'd put that as the answer.

Comment: @rfusca - I Did. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like one of the elements in the lens is physically misaligned to me.

The road in in focus to a distance well past the church steeple, so the steeple should be in focus, but it is not. This may very well be a hardware problem.